# Ionic 5 capacitor/angular preview files from external url's

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have tried previewanyfile cordova plugin to open files from external url's in Ionic 5 application. It works well with android but on IOS I noticed sometimes it doesnt preview/open PDF files. Just a grey screen with the file name on it. But strangely some PDF files open.
[file preview screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dNYF.png)

[image]

```
 previewProductDocument(url: string) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading document...',
    });
    loading.present().then(() => {
      this.previewAnyFile.preview(url).then((res) => {
        loading.dismiss();
      }).catch((err) => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.presentToast('Error previewing the document try later', 'danger');
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the plugin I have used
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/preview-any-file

capacitor version "@capacitor/core": "^2.2.0",

Noticed this behavior only in IOS simulator + on Real IOS device.
Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Special character (%2F)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) in the link is the cause of the issue.

For a quick win; either change the link or sanitise before processing.

In this case `url.replace('%2F', '/')` should work.

However, another link may, probably, contain a different character. Without being 100% sure, it worth a try [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI), which is `decodeURI(url)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I realised this issue is due to the special characters within the link. I already tried replacing charcters before it didnt work. 
But decodeURI method worked. Thanks